# #define/macro to return a function pointer to a function given in the same file

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

Say I have code

```
void 1funct() {
(...)
}

void 2funct() {
(...)
}
etc., to 

void nfunct() {
(...)
}
```

Is it possible to return the function pointer to the correct function given an n by

`#define RET_FUNC_POINTER(n) (&nfunct);` ?

Comment: Function names can't start with numbers, can they?

Comment: Two answers posted at the same time, both independently saying use an array - there you have it.

Comment: You could do it (if we ignore that identifiers can't start with digits; see answers below), but I doubt it'll give you anything. The macro parameter would have to be constant (known at preprocessing time; so it can't be a variable, and so on). And if the number is constant, you might as well write `&nfunct` directly. As others have said, you probably want an array of function pointers.

Comment: Could do something like `_##n##funct` to dodge the identifier naming rule.

Comment: Names with leading underscores, while not universally prohibited, are generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Yes — macros can concatenate source code characters into a single token using `##`:

```
#define RET_FUNC_POINTER(n) (&n ## funct);
```

*(Tokens are the invisible "building blocks" of your source code, discrete units of text that the parser generates from your code while trying to understand your program. They are roughly analogous to "words" in English, but they do not need to be separated by spaces in C++ unless omitting a space would just produce a single token: e.g. `int main` vs `intmain`, but `int *` vs `int*`. With `##` we can take the two would-be tokens `int` and `main`, and use the preprocessor to force them into `intmain` instead. Just, one of your arguments is a "variable" to the macro. Notice that you don't need to join `&` and the `n ## funct` part, as the `&` is already a separate token, and should remain that way.)*

However, you may wish to consider a nice array of pointers instead.

If the `n` is known statically at compile-time (which it must be for your macro to work) then you don't really gain anything over just writing `&1funct`, `&2funct` etc other than obfuscating your code (which isn't a gain).

Also note that your function names cannot start with digits; you'll have to choose a different naming scheme.

Comment: Is it possible to do this if the n was a char pointer stored in a variable, say  char *v = "1" instead of the integer value, if not, which adjustments do I have to make to enable this to happen?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to do this (instead of just using a `const` array), but it's quite easy to do with a macro:

```
#define RET_FUNC_POINTER(n) (n##funct)
```